# Upload background-image

Tags: jquery, background, contextmenu, jquery-file-upload

When giving a `div` the `.bgimg` class, users right click that `div` is directed to a pop up that has an file uploader to replace the `background-image` of that `div`.

Im using both **contextmenu.js** and **BlueImps fileupload.js** which both works perfectly with editing inline images.

The only thing need fixing now is this code, which seems to only replace images of child divs instead of the div with

```
$.contextMenu({
selector: '.bgimg',
className: 'data-img-title',
callback: function(key, options) {
    $('.context-menu-active').addClass('imgbg');
    $("#ImagePopUp").dialog('open');
    $("#ImagePopUp").parent().removeClass('imgbg');
    bgpname = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $("#ImagePopUp").parent().addClass('imgbg');
    $(document).on("click", "#imageselectbg", function() {
        var comgetval = $('#ImagePopUp #bgget').html();
        $('#' + bgpname).css('background-image', "url(" +
            comgetval + ")");
    });
},
items: {
    "edit": {
        name: "Edit background",
        icon: ""
    },
}
```

});

I'm no expert with js so I hope someone can help me with this.